# Tomcat multi-context deployment stops whole process if spring-boot context fails to deploy

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a very specific Tomcat configuration that I don't want to change and I am looking for a solution for *this specific* configuration.

I have declared multiple contexts (`<Context>`) for deployment inside the **conf/server.xml** file in Tomcat, something I know is not recommended. My problem is that if one of those deployments fail, the whole Tomcat process stops which terminates the rest of the applications that have successfully started. Is this behavior expected? Is there an attribute or a way to prevent this and emulate the behavior of distinct context declarations akin to the usage of `context.xml` file?

The error I'm getting is the following:

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization

with this stacktrace (for Tomcat version 8.5.24):

```
SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/auth-service]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/auth-service]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.client-html.context' in value "${app.client-html.context}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.client-html.context' in value "${app.client-html.context}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:931)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        ... 27 more
```

Sample configuration:

```
<Host name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context docBase="../../app-that-works" path="/itworks"/>
    <Context docBase="../../app-that-fails" path="/itfails"/>
</Host>
```

IMPORTANT: The **failing** application is a spring-boot application that is packaged as a .war file and running inside a vanilla tomcat, **not** the embedded tomcat way. This is important because it seems that these applications have this behavior...

DISCLAIMER: I am referring to vanilla Tomcat, **not** spring boot or embedded tomcat etc. I am not looking for such solutions, simply a solution to this specific problem.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of your exception?

Comment: Is it the whole stack trace? I would expect a couple of _"Caused by"_ more. Also which version are you using? The line number don't match Tomcat 8.5.58 (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.58/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase.java#L947)).

Comment: Ah yes this is my dev version, 8.5.24. Yes this is the Tomcat stacktrace, there is also a SpringBoot stacktrace which I didn't bother adding.

Comment: Updated the stacktrace with a more complete one acutally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

- an exception during the `start` phase (cf. [LifeCycle](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html)) of **any** component configured in `server.xml` causes the server to exit. However some exceptions (like a failed `ServletContextListener`) don't propagate.
- an error of a component added during runtime, does not cause the server to exit.

If you don't want the whole server to stop, when a context fails to start up, use auto-deployment: for each context defined in `server.xml` create a file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/<context_path>.xml` with content:

```xml
<Context docBase="/path/to/application" />
```

In your case you need to create `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/itworks.xml` and `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/itfails.xml`. See [Naming](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) for Tomcat's naming convention for XML descriptors.

**Edit**: Your stack trace suggests that we might be dealing with a Tomcat or Spring bug:

- On one side the `StandardContext` expects a `ServletContainerInitializer` to throw only `ServletException`s (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/e28fdd3e611ac7c057eda906570ee0cb61542e56/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java#L5154)) and let's all unchecked exceptions through. Remark that at the same time all exceptions from `ServletContextListener`s are caught and just logged (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/6776cb6f3213af953ec350f37084c6370acf3732/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java#L4720)).
- On the other hand Spring's `SpringServletContainerInitializer`
  should probably wrap all unchecked exceptions into a `ServletException`.

What happens in your case is that an unchecked exception makes it all the way through to the `StandardContext` and is rethrown as a `LifecycleException` stopping the server. Anyway, setting:

```xml
<Context throwOnFailure="false" ... />
```

should stop Tomcat from propagating the exception.

Comment: It is indeed a LifeCycle exception: *A child component could not be deployed* or something like that. What you describe exactly matches my investigation. I was mostly hoping for a flag or an attribute in the `<Context>` elements that would make the error not propagate. I guess this is a Tomcat limitation then and we never came across it because all the previous applications failed at the ServletContextListener but this new one, being a SpringBoot app, fails outside that which propagates the error.

Comment: Try `throwOnFailure="false"` on the `<Context>` element. Although the complete stack trace of your error would be useful to classify the problem. `ServletException`s in `ServletContainerInitializer`s and exceptions in `ServletContextListener` should not be enough to bring the server down.

Comment: I added the stacktrace. I tested the `throwOnFailure` attribute which does not seem to exist in the `<Connector>`, not `<Context>` attribute but I think it's also not available on my version of Tomcat (8.5.58).

Comment: `throwOnFailure` exists on most Tomcat components (cf. [LifecycleBase](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/LifecycleBase.html#setThrowOnFailure(boolean))).